# Implicit typecast observed in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

In my SQL Server 2K DB table there is a varchar zipcode field which happens to output incorrect character length of the zipcode when it encouters a numeric hyphenated zipcode. For example, for the values such as ABC12-1234 it would emit correct length i.e. 10, however when the zipcode is something like 21345-5 it emits its length as 5 instead of 7. I wonder how this implicit uncalledfor typecasting be avoided. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you getting this length value?

Comment: What I perceive is that while the zipcode fields encouters something like ABC12-1234 it treats is as char string and emits correct length i.e. 10 on the contrary when the field has the value 21345-5 it internally calculates it to 21340 and outputs the length to 5. Hope I could answer your question.

Comment: In other words, i can insert zipcode say 21345-5 (without single quotes) to the varchar type zipcode field and that is what i want to avoid. If the table structure is something like mytable (zipcode varchar(10)) then insert into mytable values (12345-5) should throw an error for type-mismatch which it does not.

Answer (score 2):

So your complaint is that if someone does

```
INSERT INTO YourTable(ZipCode) VALUES(21345-5)
```

i.e they omit the quotes it will get treated as

```
INSERT INTO YourTable(ZipCode) VALUES(21340)
```

and you want this to be avoided and raise an error because of the cast from `int` to `varchar`

This strict behaviour isn't possible in any version of SQL Server yet. [Though it is a moderately highly voted request on the connect site.](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/260762/add-optional-checks-for-more-robust-development)

Must all zipcodes in your locale contain a `-` character?  If so you could enforce this aspect with a check constraint otherwise you'll just need to exercise care in your insert statements.

Any inserts coming from your application should be parameterised anyway to the correct type so I assume this does only apply to manual insert statements?

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to reproduce this - this snippet works flawlessly on SQL Server 2000:

```
CREATE TABLE ZipCodeTest(ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, ZipCode VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO dbo.ZipCodeTest(ZipCode) VALUES('ABC12-1234')
INSERT INTO dbo.ZipCodeTest(ZipCode) VALUES('21345-5')
INSERT INTO dbo.ZipCodeTest(ZipCode) VALUES('ABC')
INSERT INTO dbo.ZipCodeTest(ZipCode) VALUES('32144')
```

Then I do a SELECT on that table:

```
SELECT
    ID, ZipCode, LEN(ZipCode)
FROM
    ZipCodeTest
```

and get the following output:

```
ID  ZipCode      LEN        
1   ABC12-1234    10
2   21345-5        7
3   ABC            3
4   32144          5
```

Your "problem case" (with ID = 2) shows `LEN(ZipCode) = 7` as expected.

Can you show us

- your table structure
- your SELECT statement that returns the erroneous length information??